# How to create Google subchapters?

Tags: php, html, webserver

How can I create such subchapters for Google on my website:

[image: Google subchapters of a news-page]

Is this HTML or something server specific?
And how to make this on my own homepage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're called Sitelinks, and you don't. [Google does this automatically, but only if they feel it's going to be useful for users](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334) - typically, only on high-traffic sites.

Via the Google Webmaster Tools, you can *prevent* certain pages from showing up in these suggestions, but you can't enable/add any.

Comment: Hm, Couldn´t it be possible by writing these chapters in html into the index file of the website?

Comment: You can do whatever you like on your site, it's still not going to show up in Google's search results like this.